# What fantasy story elicited this quote?

Tags: story-identification

I've read this description of a fantasy story. I suspect that it's written (or said) either derogatorily or tongue-in-cheek, but what story does it refer to?

> Transported to a surreal landscape, a young girl kills the first woman she meets and then teams up with three complete strangers to kill again.

This would be pretty old (e.g. definitely earlier than 1970s).

Comment: I've purged the comments; please take the discussion to [meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/) ([where this all started](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/is-it-good-that-story-identification-questions-are-so-well-rewarded)) or [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) (where we [have been discussing this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2919635#2919635)).

Comment: As I said in chat, I had originally debated VTC, as it seemed "general reference", but decided against that. Due to our subsequent conversation, I feel that was correct, and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*Originally posted as a comment; converted to answer per suggestion by DVK.*

Courtesy of the Trivia on Wizard of Oz @ [IMDB.com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032138/trivia), Rick Polito of the Marin Independent Journal printed in Northern California is locally famous for his droll, single-sentence summations of television programs and movies which the newspaper reports will be broadcast. For the Wizard of Oz, he wrote, "Transported to a surreal landscape, a young girl kills the first person she meets and then teams up with three strangers to kill again."

Answer (score 22):

Sounds like [The Wizard of Oz](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032138/) to me.

Comment: Definitely Wizard of Oz. Googling the phrase turns up exactly that result.

Comment: @Keith - you should make that an asnwer. Worth an accept.

Comment: Well, since Beofett nailed it, I wasn't worried.. but if the extra data is worth a vote or two, sure, why not :)

Comment: @KeithHWeston - yeah, a background of where that description came from definitely is. +1 for both answers, accept to the one with sourced proof.